# Progress bar while loading new activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, load

My Activity2 takes certain seconds to load, I need to display a progress bar while my Activity2 loads in the background.

How can I implement a progressbar that displays until my new activity opens ?

For now I have this code, but it causes seconds to be added to the load of my new activity. I think I'm actually just showing a progressbar and then loading the activity?

That is not efficient

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    CardView buttonOpen = findViewById(R.id.menu1);
    buttonOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }

            }, 5000);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the progress right before you start the new activity like this:

```java
// Hide the progressbar.
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```